# restart from 0 when array is too short

Tags: jquery

how can i manage the array to restart from 0 (in function get_hover_color)  when there are too many links and color array is too short?
thanks for helping!

till.

```
<div class="line">
<div><h2 class="color_link">DRUCKVORSTUFE</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="color_link">SCAN</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="color_link">RETUSCHEN</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="color_link">ANDRUCK</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="color_link">PDF</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="color_link">CTP</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="color_link">STACCATO</h2></div>
.............
.............
.............
........and so on........

</div>

function get_hover_color(i){

        hover_color_array = ['54cacd','e84d3a','ff3384','a0388d','231599','0d958a','629B39','33811E','F04E00','F00200','D9008F','58dbb4','093C8B','AECB27','E5B208','74204f','C26A21','DB2C17','cccf78','166C64','9A1E6E','7EADC2','00A1CE'];

return hover_color_array[i];

     }



$('.color_link').each(function(i){
            $(this).hover(
             function(){
               var $this = $( this );
               $this.data( 'prehovercolor', $this.css( 'color' ) ).css( {'color' : '#' + get_hover_color(i), 'cursor' : 'pointer' });
             },function(){
               var $this = $( this );
               $this.css( 'color', $this.data( 'prehovercolor') );
             });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
hover_color_array[i % hover_color_array.length]
```

That should give you a range which will fall within the array at all times since it takes the remainder, which can only range from `0` to `hover_color_array.length-1`

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting it? :P (its the little check like icon below the downvote button)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the modulus of the length:

```
function get_hover_color(i){

    hover_color_array = ['54cacd','e84d3a','ff3384','a0388d','231599','0d958a','629B39','33811E','F04E00','F00200','D9008F','58dbb4','093C8B','AECB27','E5B208','74204f','C26A21','DB2C17','cccf78','166C64','9A1E6E','7EADC2','00A1CE'];

k = i % hover_color_array.length;

return hover_color_array[k];

 }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/9f59bza0(v=vs.94).aspx